# Whats the information does the call_history.db file contains and how can we access it programatically in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I need to get access of call_history.db file and I want to know how to access that database and what the information is stored in it.Does it stores the incoming call,outgoing call and declined call numbers??

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.

The call history on the iPhone is not accessible to the SDK.  The data contained within any such database (or databases) is entirely an internal implementation detail of the device and may change at any time.